# Why can't I modify the properties of images by referencing them as children of their parent div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

Being that this is my HTML with the four images:

```js
    $('div#slideshow').children(function(index){
        $(this).width('90%');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
     <img style='position:relative;' width="400px" src="https://consumermediallc.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/totinos-stock-08-2014.jpg" alt="" />
     <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/66fa7962b68e90da541078fcc9efdc25/tumblr_inline_nnby3oQs8s1si7eaa_500.jpg" alt="Lightning Ghost" />
     <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr02/14/7/enhanced-3829-1400068353-2.jpg" alt="Girraffe-dog" class="slide" />
     <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2291250-terrible-grimace-men-with-shovel.jpg" alt="Purpleish Kitty" />
    </div>
```

Could you perhaps explain why this is or what I've done wrong with my jQuery command? I'm stumped.

Comment: Is there more than one element with the id "slideshow"? Also you can just do `$("#slideshow > img").width("90%");`

Comment: [Here is a working jsfiddle with your HTML and the change I suggested in the above comment.](http://jsfiddle.net/vq7bmgkz/1/)

Comment: @Pointy Post that as an answer and I'll mark you as having the correct answer. I'm absolutely god-awful at jQuery. :(

Comment: OK - I just realized what the prroblem is with yours too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.children()` function does take a parameter, but it's not intended to be a function that operates on the child elements. It's for *filtering* the child elements.

You could use `.children().each()` with your code, or you could just do this:

```
$("#slideshow > img").width("90%");
```

The library has implicit iteration built in, so when your selector matches multiple elements it will make the changes to each one automatically.

Comment: It won't let me check an answer for another 4 minutes. Sorry about the wait.

Answer (score 0):

`Children` is used for filtering, it doesn't do a callback for each element.  For that, you need `each`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div#slideshow').children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).width('90%');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <img style='position:relative;' width="400px" src="https://consumermediallc.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/totinos-stock-08-2014.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/66fa7962b68e90da541078fcc9efdc25/tumblr_inline_nnby3oQs8s1si7eaa_500.jpg" alt="Lightning Ghost" />
  <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr02/14/7/enhanced-3829-1400068353-2.jpg" alt="Girraffe-dog" class="slide" />
  <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2291250-terrible-grimace-men-with-shovel.jpg" alt="Purpleish Kitty" />
</div>
```

Or just use css:

```css
#slideshow > img {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img style='position:relative;' width="400px" src="https://consumermediallc.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/totinos-stock-08-2014.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/66fa7962b68e90da541078fcc9efdc25/tumblr_inline_nnby3oQs8s1si7eaa_500.jpg" alt="Lightning Ghost" />
  <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/2014-05/enhanced/webdr02/14/7/enhanced-3829-1400068353-2.jpg" alt="Girraffe-dog" class="slide" />
  <img src="https://www.colourbox.com/preview/2291250-terrible-grimace-men-with-shovel.jpg" alt="Purpleish Kitty" />
</div>
```

Comment: Which is better, `$("#slideshow > img").width("90%");` or `$('div#slideshow').children().each(function(index) {`?

Comment: `$("#slideshow > img").width("90%");` would be better of those two, the CSS solution would be best, if it would work in your use case.